# can anyone help me find what wrong with this code

Tags: java, arrays

can anyone help me find what wrong with this code. I am trying to write a function method that determine the second to the last occurrence of a target in an integer array. Return -1 if not in the array.

```
public static int findSecondToLast(int [] a, int target) {
    int [] b  = new int[countOfTarget (a,target)];
    int k =0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        if  (a[i]==target){
            b[k]=i;
            k++;
            return  b[ countOfTarget (a,target) - 1];
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

public static int countOfTarget (int[]a, int t){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == t) 
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: For future reference, you should post your error or bug in the title. Thanks!:)

Comment: the code will only give the first occurrence of the target not the second to last. I cant figure out why it's doing that

Comment: I fixed your compilation error. Try stepping through it using a debugger or on paper.

Comment: @user2909389 the return in your for loop is incorrect. It should happen after the loop has completed.

Comment: @BevynQ Don't change the code. How you know the questionare did like this. Dont assume and modified like this

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code as

```
public static int findSecondToLast(int[] a, int target)
    {
        int[] b = new int[countOfTarget(a, target)];
        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == target)
            {
                b[k] = i;
                k++;
                return b[ countOfTarget(a, target) - 1];
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

`return-1` statement must be outside `for loop`

Comment: I caught that too.  Too bad someone edited the problem out of the post

Comment: This is not a correct solution. The method will return the first time `a[i] == target` and the value of `b[countOfTarget(a, target) - 1]` will not have been assigned (unless `countOfTarget(a, target)` returns 1).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is much easier if you simply scan in reverse order and return the second occurrence of the element:

```
public static int findSecondToLast(int[] a, int terget) {
    int firstFound = false;
    for (int i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (a[i] == target) {
            if (firstFound) {
                return i;
            }
            firsrFound = true;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

There's no need to use the `countOfTarget` method and no need to iterate through the array three times (which is what your original code was doing).

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your function to this one:

```
public static int findSecondToLast(int [] a, int target)
{
    int prev = -1;
    int last = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        if  (a[i] == target)
        {
            prev = last;
            last = i;
        }
    return prev;
}
```